# How to reopen a function

Tags: android-studio

I have disabled the quick fix function (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) in the Android Stutio by mistake and now I want to reopen it.
I tried to change the settings, but failed because I'm not familiar with Android Stutio.Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all shortcuts in: **File -> Settings -> Keymap** 
Look for the ***Project quick fix*** function and rebind it to **ALT+ENTER** again.

> [Android Studio Tips](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html)